# How to use RSS reader plugin for displaying as posts?

Tags: rss

I am running WP 3.7.1-powered website. I would like to read news from several RSS sources and display them on one page in very similar manner as if they were posts from users of my site. Particularly, I need them to be displayed in the main area of a page (not in a widget) and I need them to be commented as regular posts. I tried "WP Simple Rss Feed Reader" and "RSS Importer", but I did not manage to configure or use them in such a way which would solve my problem. Is there any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Recommendation of plugins or themes or anything such is beyond the scope of this community. Please check http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. Now please edit the question accordingly for seeking help from the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-[FeedWordPress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/feedwordpress/)

2-
[WP RSS Multi Importer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-multi-importer/)

use one of these, which suits you.